# Use a keyboard without waking Mac's monitor?

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake

I'd like to be able to hit a key combo on my keyboard without it waking my Mac's monitor.

Let's say my monitor is asleep and I want to press a function key to do something (volume up/down, iTunes next/back, or something else), if my monitor is asleep, pressing the key wakes the monitor instead of executing the function I've assigned...  so...  I have to press the button twice, but what's particularly annoying is that I have to put my monitor to sleep again.

I want to be able to use hotkeys without waking my monitor.  Is this possible?  It's a USB keyboard (actually, it's a Flirc IR receiver USB dongle that a Mac sees as a keyboard.  Flirc plus BetterTouchTool makes it easy to use a universal remote to control a Mac...  but drat, I can't figure out how to keep the monitor asleep).

I'm running the latest version of macOS.

Comment: As a test, what happens if you totally power off the monitor? Does the dongle still require having the button pressed twice? If so, what about totally unplugging the monitor (obviously, this is _not_ a solution), I'm just trying to do a couple of tests to see how the behaviour changes (if at all).

Comment: Powering off the monitor is what I'm currently doing and it's annoying for many reasons.  It works, but what I want is the ability to have the monitor stay asleep.

Comment: Thanks - that's good to know - it means that what you want to do _may_ be feasible. Now the challenge is to try and find out how. I'll do a bit of digging, but perhaps in the meantime someone else will have a solution for you! :)